# Button background image won't show

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating buttons with background images for a navigation system. The frustrating thing is that all of the background images show correctly in the CODA test-browser so I know the file paths are correct, but they don't show at all in Chrome/Firefox/Safari. If anyone has any advice they can offer I would greatly appreciate it.

Link to test-site: http://parkerrichard.com/new/index.html

HTML

```
    <nav class="centered" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="centered">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><button class="design"></button></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><button class="photo"></button></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><button class="music"></button></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><button class="art"></button></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><button class="parker"></button></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-glyphs">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav-words">
            <li>
                <a href="#">ART</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">MUSIC</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">PHOTO</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">DESIGN</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div><!--/container -->
</nav><!--/navbar -->
```

CSS

```
nav button {
    border-radius:50%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 50% !important;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
}

.parker {
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: transparent url('img/parker.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    cursor: hand;
}

.art {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: transparent url('img/art.jpg');
}

.music {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: transparent url('img/music.jpg');
}

.photo {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: transparent url('img/photo.jpg');
}

.design {
    margin-left: -300px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: transparent url('img/design.jpg');
}
```

Comment: did you checked background image path url? when i use inspect element im getting mgs like "failed to load the given url"

Comment: But its works fine for me in firefox and chrome.

Comment: It works correctly now, thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of shorthand try explicitly setting the values

Ex:

```
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url(...);
```

Comment: it turned out to be an error in the file path after all, the shorthand works

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake! The background images simply needed a "../" before each url (I had forgotten my css was in its own folder within the root directory)

Answer (score 0):

Add Opacity value for all button classes

```
.art, .parker, .music, .photo, .design {
opacity:0.5;
}
```